# Which library to use in C++ for fast DCT's?

Tags: c++, libraries

I need to apply a 1D type-II DCT ([Discrete Cosine Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)) to each column of a matrix while normalizing the result in C++. Effectively, I want to multiply my matrix with an orthogonal type-II DCT-matrix (while avoiding the performance cost of matrix multiplication, of course).

Since this seems like an important computational kernel in many applications, isn't there a highly optimized library for this purpose out there? After searching for a bit I can find a couple of implementations, but I don't know if they're good. I was expecting a function somewhere in a well-known library such as Boost or Eigen. After all, in Python everything I need to do is this (using SciPy): `dct(x, norm='ortho')`

Comment: What do you mean by DCT? Discrete Cosine Transform? I would strongly suggest you always define an acronym when you first use it, just because you know what it means doesn't mean everybody else does

Comment: FFTW (http://www.fftw.org/) is one of the leading c++ FFT libraries and is pretty easy to use. I would also try Intel's MKL FFT routines (which include wrappers for FFTW), as you may find other related linear algebra utilities to solve your problem.

Comment: Here is a related post using FFTW for DCT
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530613/using-fftw3-library-for-dct

Comment: As @CharlieS mentioned, MKL is frequently used in HPC for FFT computations.

Comment: @IanBush Good point, I wanted to add it myself now but just saw someone else edited it in already.

Comment: @CharlieS and M.A: Thank you for your comments. I decided to try out FFTW since it seems to have everything I need (apart from normalization, but I can do that myself) and I read the Intel MKL doesn't port well to non-Intel CPU's, so I'd rather use other libraries. Although I assume, if it's just a wrapper here, there's no performance cost in this particular case.

Comment: @Wout12345 the MKL FFTW wrappers use MKL's libraries but with a similar signature so you can compare performance and convert to MKL if you so desire. Personally, I'd recommend FFTW as its open source and easy to get help, and probably matches or outperforms MKL in many situations.

Comment: @CharlieS I concur to FFTW being a very sensible choice. A word of caution concerning MKL wrappers: some of them are empty (i.e. the planner would return an empty plan, without warning). Related to this question, this is the case for the multidimensional DCTs (the planner of which is empty in MKL FFTW). source : https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-developer-reference-c/top/appendix-d-fftw-interface-to-intel-math-kernel-library/fftw3-interface-to-intel-math-kernel-library/using-fftw3-wrappers.html